# How to hide a section when click outside the section in my HTML page?

Tags: javascript

Please check it. Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4467yz37/

When I do click in the Link it works good (`Show and Hide`). The only problem existing it's when I want to hide the Items section doing click outside the Link and the Items (that is in the `Body` except in the Items section).

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
(function(document) {    
    var alterNav = function() {
        var item = document.querySelector('.items');
        var link = document.querySelector('.clickme');
        var theClass = 'display';
        var itemIsOpened = false;

        if (link) {
            link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                if (!itemIsOpened) {
                    itemIsOpened = true;
                    addClass(item, theClass);
                } else {
                    itemIsOpened = false;
                    removeClass(item, theClass);
                }
            });
        }
    };    

    var addClass = function (element, className) {
        if (!element) {
            return;
        }
        element.className = element.className.replace(/\s+$/gi, '') + ' ' + className;
    };

    var removeClass = function(element, className) {
        if (!element) {
            return;
        }
        element.className = element.className.replace(className, '');
    };    

    alterNav();
})(document);
```

---

I try to solve it creating another variable with the tag `Html` or `Body` and alter the JS code, but it still don't working good: http://jsfiddle.net/g1d321rv/2/

```
var link = document.querySelector('body');
```

Comment: So you want to hide items that are shown, after click `Show`, by clicking anywhere on the page. is this what you want?

Comment: Yes sir. To show only by clicking in the Link, and to hide by clicking anywhere the page except in the Items shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manipulated your code a bit. Do you use jquery? I assumend that you are not using jquery.Here jsfiddle :

- http://jsfiddle.net/9fpf07mt/

  ```
  window.onclick = function (e) {
      console.log(e);
      if (!itemIsOpened) {
          if (e.target == link) {
              itemIsOpened = true;
              addClass(item, theClass);
          }
      } else {
          if (!isChild(e.target, item)) {
              itemIsOpened = false;
              removeClass(item, theClass);
          }
      }
  };
  ```

edit for last request:

```
link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
```

Comment: "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Comment: @caslaner Is it possible to do with `addEventListener` only? Because with `window.onclick` it alter the URL!

Comment: @caslaner - Finally I got it! Thanks so much! I only added `e.preventDefault();` to the function and works fine!